# Telerik RadGrid GridTemplateColumns programmatically

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I need to make multiple RadGrids with editable columns throughout them.  I understand how to make bound columns and make template columns but i do not know how to place Textbox's and Dropdownlists inside of those template columns.

```
string templateColumnName = "ContactName";
GridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
templateColumn.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate(templateColumnName);
templateColumn.HeaderText = templateColumnName;
```

what do I do after this.

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate the desired webcontrol within the container. This happens in the InstantiateIn method. I'd recommend that you examine this link:
[Programmatic creation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html#Section4)

If you need more info, you can also examine this one:
[Creating Web Server Control Templates Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289501.aspx)

Let us know if you have any specific question about that.